# how handle none from a SQL Selection in if instructions

Tags: python, mysql, database, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

Hello Stackoverflow Communtiy,

For a school project, I am currently writing a Python program on a Raspberry Pi 3, with database connection.
The Raspberry Pi is connected to an RFID scanner.

We want to record absences.
First, if there is NULL in the database, if the student comes 5 minutes late, the NULL should be replaced by 5 minutes. and if he leaves earlier than the lesson ends, the time should be added.

I currently read None (NULL) from the database, I would like to use it in an IF statement.
So if = NULL then first statement Else the other.
In doing so, I always get the following error.

Allready tryt to Delcare the result as None before its reading from the Database

```
 StudentID = str(result[0][0])
 c.execute("Select %s FROM  Attendances WHERE StudentID  = %s AND Date = %s 
 AND %s IS NULL  " % (("Std" +str((result1[0] 
 [1]))),StudentID,str((datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'))),("Std" + 
 +str((result1[0][1])))))
 result3 = c.fetchall



if str(result3[0][0]) is None :



                c.execute("UPDATE Attendances SET %s = (Select current_time() - MIN(LessonStart)  from LessonTime where current_time() < LessonsEnds) WHERE SchuelerID  = %s AND Datum = %s AND %s IS NULL  " % (("Std" +str((result1[0][1]))),SchuelerID,str((datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'))),("Std" +str((result1[0][1]))))),

                print (datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
                print 'Successfully registered as present'

            else:
                c.execute("UPDATE Attendances SET %s =  %s  +   (Select current_time() - MIN(LessonEnds)  from LessonTime where current_time() < LessonsEnds) WHERE StudentID  = %s AND Date = %s AND %s IS NOT NULL  " % (("Std" +str((result1[0][1]))),("Std" +str((result1[0][1]))),SchuelerID,str((datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d'))),("Std" +str((result1[0][1])))))
```

TypeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

Answer (score 0):

I see error on line `result3=c.fetchall`. `fetchall` is function so you must call it with brackets: `fetchall()`. 
Next mistake is: When you do `str(result[0][0])` it is no more Boolean, but string.
So if `result[0][0]` will be `None`, after conversion with `str(result[0][0])` it will contain string `"None"`. So your statement now is like `if ("None" == None)` which will be always False.

Comment: str(result[0][0]) 
does not matter for what I have do to before  without the IF instruction it works without problems

str(result3[0][0]) 
There, the NULL is stored in it when I select it

When i add () to fetchall i getting following error IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: "after conversion with str(result[0][0]) it will contain string "None". So your statement now is like if ("None" == None) which will be always False."

How do i check then if its null ? 
Like if Lesson3 (Starts 09:30) for StudentA NULL, because he didnt scan yet, when he scan look for the NULL if its NULL then insert first time if its not null add the other time

Comment: Probably you have error in passing arguments into `SELECT` statement. Just for DEBUGGING try hardcode parameters into SELECT statement, and you will see if error persists. Like: `Select * FROM  Attendances WHERE StudentID  = 1 AND Date = 2019/01/25 AND absence IS NULL  `

Comment: From the Select im getting 


'((datetime.date(2019, 1, 25), 22L, None, None, None, None, None, None, None),)'   and more Nones ^^

(a) for Lesson1 
Now i want to look if None(a) = None then doing the first thing, if not none then doing the second one.